# NodeJs-TypeError: Category.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am working on NodeJs application its blog application. i am trying to fetch
Category data, fetching process i am getting this error

```
TypeError: Category.find is not a function
    at getCategories (D:\OnlyNodeJs\CMS App\controllers\adminController.js:54:18)
```

here is file..

## adminController.js

```
const Category = require('../models/CategoryModel');
 getCategories: (req, res) => {

        Category.find()
               .then(cats => {
                res.render('admin/category/index', { categories: cats});
        });
    },
```

## adminRoutes.js

```
router.route('/category')
      .get(adminController.getCategories);
```

## CategoryModels.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({

    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }


});

module.exports = {Category: mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema )};
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You export an object with a Category prop, but then you import it as though the Category is the only thing being exported. Either update the import to :

```
const { Category }  = require('../models/CategoryModel');
```

Or update the export to:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema);
```